# How to find values in string, manipulate and replace them

Tags: python, regex

How to find values in string, add specific value to each of them and replace output with fixed string.

```
import re
def _replace(content):
    #x = float(content.group(4))+20
    #y = float(content.group(6))+20
    return content.group(6)
print re.sub('<g(\s)transform="matrix\((.*)(\s)(.*)(\s)(.*)\)\"', _replace, '<g transform="matrix(0.412445 -0.0982513 0.0982513 0.412445 -5.77618 67.0025)">')
```

Comment: If you indent your code by 4 spaces, it will be nicely formatted.

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see what you've already tried. You mentioned that your code is being "stripped"... You can use the code snippet (braces icon) formatting tool to add a block of code.  Just copy-paste it in, highlight the code block, and press the braces icon.  (It just indents the code snippet by 4 spaces, which is what stackoverflow uses to indicate a code block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I should repeat the usual warning about not parsing XML with regexes.  It's a bad idea, and it will *never* work for all cases.  If you're actually trying to parse the full xml document, [use an XML parser](http://diveintopython.net/xml_processing/).

That having been said, I'm guilty of doing quick and dirty stuff like this all the time.  If you really just need a one-off solution, a simple regex can often get the job done. Just be aware that it will come back to haunt you as soon as you run into something more complex!

Next, I confess to not being much of a regex wiz, but here's how I'd modify your code snippet:

```
import re

def _replace(content):
    values = [float(val) for val in content.group(2).split()]
    values[3] += 20
    values[5] += 100
    values = ['{0}'.format(val) for val in values]
    return content.group(1) + ' '.join(values) + content.group(3)

test_string = '<g transform="matrix(0.412445 -0.0982513 0.0982513 0.412445 -5.77618 67.0025)">'
pattern = r'(transform=\"matrix\()(.*?)(\))'
print test_string
print re.sub(pattern, _replace, test_string)
```

Comment: +1 I was about to post very similar code. I can't think of a better way either.

Comment: Thank you for your commitment and fast answer! I think it will be good for now, however I have to take a closer look into XML parser.